# Android async-http - java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, ssl, android-async-http

I using `async-http` library and when our server started using https, I got this error:

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found
```

How can I turn on ignoring check of certificate (Our certificate doesn't complete yet).

Answer (score 1):

See this post 
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#HttpsExample

1. The CA that issued the server certificate was unknown
2. The server certificate wasn't signed by a CA, but was self signed
3. The server configuration is missing an intermediate CA